# VSTO Outlook add-in error after Office update

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I have been using this code for many years for my custom tab (Ribbon Designer, TabReadMessage, for current opened e-mail). But after an Office update this summer it throws me an error on first row in code.

```
Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

- Running this addin on Outlook 2013 don't give any error.
- Running on Outlook 365 build version 1705 - no problem.
- Running on Outlook 365 build version 1706 and above - gives me error.

It works fine the first time I open the e-mail, but when I close the e-mail and open again I get the error (when debugging): "`NullReferenceException occured`"

Could someone explain to me why? Maybe you could reproduce the error?

I have Visual Studio 2012 (VSTO + VB.Net).
Here is what I do to reproduce:

1. Create a Outlook 2013 add-in
2. Add a Ribbon item (Visual Designer) and set RibbonType to "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read".
3. Change Tab to TabReadMessage.
4. Add a Button to the Tab.
5. Set Debug, Exceptions, Common language Runtime Exceptions, System, Check "Thrown" in System.NullReferenceException.
6. Add code to Ribbon1_Load and run/debugg:

   ```
   Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
       MsgBox(mailItem.Subject)
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: That would mean that either .Application.ActiveInspector is null or .ActiveInspector.CurrentItem is null, How do you use MailItem in Ribbon.Load?

Comment: I use it for checking a UserProperties. Depending on that property I will show one or more buttons in the ribbon. Do you understand why it is null in the later versions (1706 and above)?

Comment: Can you run your code under the debugger or at least do some kind of logging to see which conditions causes the problem?

Comment: The error I get when debugging is "NullReferenceException occured". I have to Set Debug, Exeptions to get more info.
I appreciate your help since I'm quite a novice at this. I updated my question. Are you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: So when you set the break point and watch the values, which object is null?

Comment: Application.ActiveInspector is "Nothing".

Comment: I don't use VSTO, but the current context should be exposed through the event handler arguments so that you don't have to use Application.ActiveInspector. Same with the buttons - you can use visible callbacks on each button to show/hide them appropriately instead of using Ribbon_Load event.

Comment: Ok, I have to look into that. Still I don't understand what is wrong with
my approach... it works fine on Outlook 2013 but not latest 365 version.

Comment: It simply means that by the time Ribbon1_Load event fires, Outlook does not think there is an active inspector yet, e.g. it might be hidden at that point.